# Why i am getting ValueError at /login The given username must be set in Request Method POST- DJANGO

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-views, django-templates

ValueError at /login
The given username must be set
Request Method: POST

Below is the code for views.py and signup.html

```
views.py

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']
        name = request.POST.get('fname')
        passw = request.POST['pass']
        my_user = User.objects.create_user(username=name,email=email,password=passw)
        my_user.save()
        if not email:
            messages.error("Please Fill Correct Credentials.{0} is missing".format(email))
        if not name:
            messages.error("Please Fill Correct Credentials.{0} is missing".format(name))
        if not passw:
            messages.error("Please Fill Correct Credentials.{0} is missing".format(passw))
    return render(request,'signup.html')
```

---

```
signup.html

{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Login V1</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'images/icons/favicon.ico' %}"/>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'vendor/animate/animate.css' %}">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css' %}">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'vendor/select2/select2.min.css' %}">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/util.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
</head>
<body>

    <div class="limiter">
        <div class="container-login100">
            <div class="wrap-login100">
                <div class="login100-pic js-tilt" data-tilt>
                    <img src="{% static 'img/img-01.png' %}" alt="IMG">
                </div>

                <form class="login100-form validate-form" method="POST">
                    <span class="login100-form-title">
                        Signup
                    </span>

                                        {% csrf_token %}

                        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Username is required">
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Username" required>
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                        <span class="symbol-input100">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Valid email is required: ex@abc.xyz">
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                        <span class="symbol-input100">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Password is required">
                        <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" required>
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                        <span class="symbol-input100">
                            <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                        <button class="login100-form-btn">
                            Login
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center p-t-12">
                        <span class="txt1">
                            Forgot
                        </span>
                        <a class="txt2" href="#">
                            Username / Password?
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center p-t-136">
                        <a class="txt2" href="#">
                            Create your Account
                            <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right m-l-5" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="{% static 'vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js' %}"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/js/popper.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="{% static 'vendor/select2/select2.min.js' %}"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="{% static 'vendor/tilt/tilt.jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script >
        $('.js-tilt').tilt({
            scale: 1.1
        })
    </script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="{% static 'js/login.js' %}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Above is the code of views.py and signup.html

It doesn't even run the html file direct to the error page

Why This is error this error is coming?

Please explain me how you Fix the solution because i am new to Django

Request Method is Post

Comment: Can you share the full error traceback?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aksharpandey/djangomycodingguide/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 56, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/aksharpandey/djangomycodingguide/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    self.check_response(response, callback)
  File "/Users/aksharpandey/djangomycodingguide/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 332, in check_response
    raise ValueError(

Comment: Full error traceback